# Using AutoIt to Manipulate Save Dialogs

Tags: ruby, scripting, watir, autoit

I'm attempting to use AutoIt in a Ruby script I am writing to automatically download files. The script successfully gets to the save file prompt so I just need a way to actually download the file.

Problem for me at least, is that, the examples I've found tend to be very general and not related to any specific example. I've found code to do this, but it's very difficult to know what should be altered for my specific case of file dialog.

If anyone either has a good solution to this, another method, or a good reference to something that has perhaps went by unnoticed, I would be most obliged. Thanks again.

EDIT:
Also, my save prompt consists of radio buttons which I have not seen any documentation for. I'm using Firefox to do this script. Perhaps there are some options I can set in my browser to eliminate this hurtle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to use the AutoIt3 Window Info tool (Au3Info) to identify the controls you need to use, then you use ControlCommand with "Check" or "Uncheck" for radios, and then the usual mix of epic AutoIt functions to do what it does best.

As an alternative (and easier) solution, try InetGet to download the file directly. It would be much better as you no longer have to worry about the user not having firefox, or ff changing the dialog.